# Searching + in a GET service is converted to a white space

Tags: ios, rest

Am trying to hit a GET service with search keyword as "R+Co", provided in the URL. But the service is receiving as "R Co" which is affecting the search logic. Can we read this as '+' itself in the service?? Thanks in Advance!!

Edit : The service is called from iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS you can encode the url string into UTF8 as

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use URL Encoding while making GET request.

See [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Encode the query String parameter which is your search keyword.

```
URLEncoder.encode("R+Co","UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks, but am calling the service from iOS app.

Comment: You can use this method in iOS app too. It is defined in java.net package. At server side, where you receive this parameter value, you dont have to decode. You will get string R+Co.

Comment: Yeah, I got the same for iOS. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This can be escaped using character set using ASCII Encoding Reference. For '+' we can use '%2B'. Now 'R+Co' is read as it is and the service is hit with 'R%2BCo'.

Comment: URL Encoder does the same thing. It will also replace other special characters too.